# ffmpeg process saying it is erroring

Tags: java, process, runtime

I am using **FFMPEG** to convert an audio file. I call the command line and in turn **FFMPEG** from Java. I do this using Runtime and Process *Runtime.exec()*. For the process I have an *InputStream and an ErrorStream*. For some reason, even though the FFMPEG commands works fine, it prints out from the Error stream giving the impression it has failed. Anyone know why this might be happening? Obviously it's not a major issue as it does work fine, but if for some reason it does actually error, or someone new to the project does not realise this is how it works it could be confusing.
Any ideas? 
Here is the relevant code:

```
        Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
        System.out.println("Execing " + cmd);
        Process proc = rt.exec(cmd);

        StreamGobbler errorGobbler = new StreamGobbler(proc.getErrorStream(), "ERROR");

        // any output?
        StreamGobbler outputGobbler = new StreamGobbler(proc.getInputStream(), "OUTPUT");
        // kick them off
        errorGobbler.start();
        outputGobbler.start();

        // any error???
        int exitVal = proc.waitFor();
        System.out.println("ExitValue: " + exitVal);
```

And the StreamGobbler class:

```
class StreamGobbler extends Thread {
InputStream is;
String      type;

StreamGobbler(InputStream is, String type) {
    this.is = is;
    this.type = type;
}

public void run() {
    try {
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
        String line = null;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
            System.out.println(type + ">" + line);
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you didn't share with us what the `stderr` output was?

Comment: It was just the output from FFMPEG saying it is converting the file, and the various settings of the file. I didn't think it was relevant.

Comment: But how do you think you can be helped without saying what's going on? Of course it is relevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are experiencing is the standard practice across all *NIX tools: they send the "business value" data to `stdout` and separately send any diagnostic output to `stderr`. This is an important hallmark of tools written in the "small is beautiful" paradigm, which greatly values the concept of *piping* one tool's output into the next one's input, thereby creating an ad-hoc chain of information processing. The complete scheme would break down if the tool sent "Processing... 50% done" kind of output to `stdout`.

Feel free to ignore such output on `stderr`, but make sure you *consume* it, as you are doing now, in order to avoid blocking due to overfull output buffers.

Comment: Thanks. In future I will post the output too!